# How can I use Shapes.AddShape method to add Camera Object

Tags: excel, shapes, excel-2010, vba

If I record the macro. I see this code.

```
Selection.Copy
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(, 480.75, 171#, 63#, 63#).Select
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Picture 2")).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

When I looked at the MsoAutoShapeType enumaration I couldn't see camera object.

And if I change any value it gives exception... (, 480.75, 171#, 63#, 63#)
the documentation says that these values are top,left,width and height ...

I want to write a method that can create camera objects any range I give

```
Sub TakePhoto(myRange As String, myPicture As String)
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub TakePhoto(rngSource As Excel.Range, rngTarget As Excel.Range)
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
Dim shpPicture As Excel.Shape

Set ws = rngTarget.Parent
rngSource.Copy
ws.Pictures.Paste Link:=True
Set shpPicture = ws.Shapes(ws.Shapes.Count)
With shpPicture
    .Top = rngTarget.Top
    .Left = rngTarget.Left
End With
End Sub
```

Call it like this:

```
Sub test()
TakePhoto Sheet2.Range("A1:C4"), Sheet1.Range("c5")
End Sub
```